# Render Failed when ListVieWebPart sorted by more than 2 columns

Tags: sharepoint

Does anyone know if it's possible have  a sharepoint lsit view sort by more than 2 columns. Wned I go to modify the view in the UI I'm only allowed to enter two sort fileds. I tried to do it in the Source like this:

```
> <Query>
>           <GroupBy Collapse="TRUE" GroupLimit="100">
>             <FieldRef Name="Category" />
>             <FieldRef Name="SubCategory" />
>             <FieldRef Name="Topic" />
>           </GroupBy>
>           <OrderBy>
>             <FieldRef Name="Category" />
>             <FieldRef Name="SubCategory" />
>             <FieldRef Name="Topic" />
>           </OrderBy>
>         </Query>
```

I get an error on the page:

```
<!-- #RENDER FAILED -->
```

Answer (score 2):

I just used the Caml Query Builder from U2U and the query below runs fine against my 2010 server.  I don't have a 2007 server to test it against so I can't gurarantee it will work for you.  Get the tool though, it will help a LOT!

http://www.u2u.be/Res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx

**UPDATE:** New tool for SharePoint 2010
http://karinebosch.wordpress.com/2012/05/12/caml-designer/

```
<Query>
  <OrderBy>
    <FieldRef Name="ID" Ascending="True" />
    <FieldRef Name="_DCDateCreated" Ascending="False" />
    <FieldRef Name="_UIVersionString" Ascending="True" />
    <FieldRef Name='Created' Ascending='True' />
  </OrderBy>
</Query>
```